# How count days between custom hours like 8:30 Am to 18:00 Pm is One days oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle11g, count

can any one help me oracle query two dates between day count only 8:30  to 6:00 Pm after submit record it

If submit record between 8:30 am to 6:00 Pm it will Count one days. if submit record after 6:00 PM it will next days record

Answer (score 1):

> if submit record after 6:00 PM it will next days record:

If you want to count dates by day starting from 18:00 the previous day to 18:00 of that day then you can just add 6 hours minus 1 second to the date before truncating and then group by that:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC( date_column + INTERVAL '5:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND ) AS date_column,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY
       TRUNC( date_column + INTERVAL '5:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND )
ORDER BY
       date_column;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( date_column ) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01' + LEVEL * INTERVAL '1' HOUR
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 50;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> DATE_COLUMN         | COUNT(*)
> :------------------ | -------:
> 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |       18
> 2020-01-02 00:00:00 |       24
> 2020-01-03 00:00:00 |        8
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a7ce0933c8975897497523700ce4b158)*

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `CASE`: if date column is called `datum` (as in my example) and its *hours* are after 18:00 (i.e. 6 PM) then make it "tomorrow at 10 AM" (so it fits into the next day). Else, take "today's" date. Something like this:

```
with data as
  (select t.*,
          case when to_char(t.datum, 'hh24mi') > '1800' then trunc(t.datum + 1) + 10/24
               else t.datum
          end datum
   from your_table t
  )
select trunc(d.datum) datum,
       count(*)
from data d
group by trunc(d.datum)
```

Comment: `18:00:01` is after `18:00:00` but this will not shift it to the next day until `19:00:00`.

Comment: Right! Thank you, fixed.